# How to redirect web services call to an other server?

Tags: .net, web-services

I have an architecture divided in two part :

- the main server connected
- 4 slave servers that are here only for computing results of some resource-consuming web services

The problem :
How can I do to redirect some SOAP call (depending on the soapaction) from the master to one of the others (randomly).

My solution :
I have an http handler that choose if we redirect the request or not, if yes it write the full incoming request in a new HttpRequest and write the incoming response in the Response.
And this works well in production, but I don't like it, mainly because it's an in-house solution and I don't think we are the best at this kind of job, and my solution doesn't support soap 1.2.

System : Windows server 2005, .net 2.0

Is there any better solution ? already build and debugged ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This already is a good solution, isn't it?

Redirecting incoming requests to different physical machines is often done on network level, e.g. round-robin DNS for load distribution etc. However, I don't think you can apply that in this scenario.

If if works, don't fix it.

Comment: yes but the solution is not really stable, and it's not my speciality to build that kind of component, so I'd rather trust someone else solution than use my buggy one.

Comment: Why is it not stable, what are the problems with it?

Comment: It's really hard to debug, there is some behaviour I can't explain, and don't handle GET or SOAP1.2 request